# how to embedd nglview in pyqt5 window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, protein-database

I am trying to implement a application using pyqt5 where I wish to show protein structure using nglview in the application window, is it possible to do so. If yes, can anybody suggest how to embedd the nglview in pyqt5 or any similar package like nglview without using jupyter to show protein structure

Answer (score 0):

nglview is IPython/Jupyter widget. Jupyter is web application, frontend runs inside browser. You can use `QProcess` to start `jupyter notebook` and open notebook url in `QWebEngineView`.